# My PC hangs in at power on after Ubuntu shutdown

Tags: boot, power-management

I shutdown my Ubuntu 16.04 normally but when I later power up my PC it sits there with the lights under the power key and the F2 key on. I then have to power off the PC and then power on to get to BIOS.
My PC BIOS requires a password to complete and my home folder is encrypted requiring a password to complete startup.
My PC is an ASUS ZenBook UX305 running dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10. The latter came with the PC.
There are no problems if I have been running Windows 10, shut it down and power my PC on after that.